# Using a history table, how can I identify each period of time in which any task is active, and reduce the data set to non-overlapping date periods

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a history table in Teradata that contains information about tasks that occurred on an account. In typical history table fashion, the data present has a Load (Valid From) and Replace (Valid To) date.

In my environment, current/unterminated records have a 1/1/3000 date and all data loads occur shortly after midnight the day after the changes were completed in the system - so Load Dates always trail the Start Date by one day.

Some sample data might look like this (I have added Col "R" to reference row numbers, it does not exist in the table):

| R | ACCT_NUM | TASK_NM | TASK_STAT | START_DT | END_DT | LD_DT | RPLC_DT | LGLC_DEL | CURR_ROW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0123456 | TASK_01 | O | 2018-05-01 | NULL | 2018-05-02 | 2018-05-16 | N | N |
| 2 | 0123456 | TASK_01 | C | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-15 | 2018-05-16 | 2018-08-16 | N | N |
| 3 | 0123456 | TASK_01 | C | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-15 | 2018-08-16 | 3000-01-01 | Y | Y |
| 4 | 0123456 | TASK_02 | O | 2018-05-05 | NULL | 2018-05-06 | 2018-05-19 | N | N |
| 5 | 0123456 | TASK_02 | C | 2018-05-05 | 2018-05-18 | 2018-05-19 | 2018-08-19 | N | N |
| 6 | 0123456 | TASK_03 | O | 2020-02-01 | NULL | 2020-02-02 | 2020-05-16 | N | N |
| 7 | 0123456 | TASK_03 | C | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-15 | 2020-02-16 | 2020-04-16 | N | N |
| 8 | 0123456 | TASK_03 | C | 2020-02-01 | 2020-02-15 | 2020-04-16 | 3000-01-01 | Y | Y |
| 9 | 0123456 | TASK_04 | C | 2022-03-01 | NULL | 2022-03-02 | 3000-01-01 | N | Y |

The place where I am struggling is that **I need to identify each unique time period in which *any* task is active on a given account**. If multiple tasks were active during overlapping time periods, then I need to identify the start date for the first task opened and the end date for the last overlapping task. (It is also possible that TASK_02 could both start and finish before TASK_01 finishes, so I would need the start/end dates related to task_01 in that type of scenario).

Using the above sample data, I would want to get an output as follows:

| Account # | Active Start Dt | Active End Dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0123456 | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-19 |
| 0123456 | 2020-02-01 | 2018-02-15 |
| 0123456 | 2022-03-01 | 3000-01-01 |

Task 1 started, and then task 2 opened. Task 1 completed but task 2 was still open. So I need the Start Date of Task 1 (from Row 1) and the End Date of Task 2 (from Row 4 or 5). Later, Task 3 is opened during its own timeframe which creates a new record, and finally Task 4 is currently open.

I have tried quite a few things unsuccessfully, including but unfortunately not limited to:

- Taking only 'Task Status = Open' records since the Replace Date would be updated with the ending date, but from here I'm unsure of how to best make the comparison to address the overlapping timeframes.
- Utilizing Lead/Lag functions to identify the next record Load Date, but again, since tasks can occur in any order, this created incorrect timeframes since I couldn't dynamically identify the next replace date that I needed
- Attempting to identify unique Load Dates of open tasks in a sub query, and then self joining back to the to the task table but this just created duplicates where multiple things were valid on a given day

I cannot provide the literal code I've written due to privacy restrictions, however, here is mock code for anyone will to provide guidance that could help get me going in the right direction:

```
SELECT
   ACCT_NUM
   ,TASK_NM
   ,TASK_STAT
   ,START_DT
   ,END_DT
   --,[other 'unimportant' fields that can change and create change records]
   ,LD_DT - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS LD_DT --SIMULATE START_DT
   ,RPLC_DT - INTERVAL '1' DAY AS LD_DT --SIMULATE END_DT ON "TASK_STAT = 'O'" RECORDS
   ,LGLC_DEL
   ,CURR_ROW
FROM
   TBL_TASK_HIST
WHERE
   TASK_STAT = 'O'
```

Sorry about the long summary, was trying to provide solid/clear detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Teradata's NORMALIZE to combine periods that overlap or meet. Based on your sample data, it appears this would work; you may need to adjust slightly for the real data.

```
SELECT ACCT_NUM, 
       BEGIN(PD) AS ACTIVE_START_DT,
       PRIOR(END(PD)) AS ACTIVE_END_DT
FROM 
 (SELECT NORMALIZE ACCT_NUM,
   PERIOD(START_DT,
       NEXT(COALESCE(END_DT,
          CASE WHEN TASK_STAT='O' and CURR_ROW='N'
          THEN START_DT
          ELSE DATE'3000-01-01' 
          END       )
            )
         ) AS PD
  FROM TBL_TASK_HIST
 ) N
 ORDER BY ACCT_NUM, ACTIVE_START_DT;
```

NORMALIZE requires a PERIOD data type so we use the `PERIOD()` constructor in the inner query and the `BEGIN()` and `END()` functions to convert back to two columns in the outer query. Since a PERIOD does not include the ending date/time bound (it's a "closed/open interval") we adjust the ending value with `NEXT()` and `PRIOR()` functions.

Maybe you could base the logic on LD_DT, RPLC_DT to avoid having to handle NULL END_DT, but it seems better to use the "business" columns if possible versus the ETL metadata.

Comment: If you need some of the "other unimportant fields" then join the normalized result back to the original table to pick them up.

Comment: This NORMALIZE function is amazing - I can't believe I didn't know about it before. I tested it when I got into the office this morning and staged and ran real data through it and in all of my testing it seemed to do exactly what I was after. Whether tasks occurred immediately back to back, or overlapped in some form, this grabbed the correct set of dates in each instance. I was then able to use the Begin/End to parse those back out into appropriate Load/Replace dates. Thank you.